# evaluate string check if integer

Tags: ruby

I am trying to output only integer values from this array.

```
perms=["12+2*4","2+2","-2+","12+34-","12-3/4"]
perms.each do |line|
    if (line.to_s =~ /^\d+(?:[+\/*-]\d+)*$/)
        puts "#{line}"
        if(!(eval(line).to_s=~ /\A\d+\z/))
            puts "#{line}=#{eval(line)}"
        end
    end
```

I am getting:

```
12+2*4
2+2
12-3/4
```

instead of what I expected:

```
12+2*4
12+2*4=20
2+2
2+2=4
```

(12-3/4 does not evaluate to an integer so should not be included here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=~` operator returns nil if it doesn't match the string with the regex. If it does find a match it returns the offset of the match found. Because of this you're either expecting `nil` or an `integer`. Your second if statement is negating what is returned by the match. If you negate `nil` you get `true` but if you negate an integer you get `false`. This means your logic is backwards. By adding the check against `nil` the logic will work as expected.

```
perms=["12+2*4","2+2","-2+","12+34-","12-3/4"]
perms.each do |line|
    if (line.to_s =~ /^\d+(?:[+\/*-]\d+)*$/)
        puts "#{line}"
        if(!(eval(line).to_s =~ /\A\d+\z/).nil?)
            puts "#{line}=#{eval(line)}"
        end
    end
end
```

With this understanding you could even remove the negate operation entirely to achieve the same result. To go along with this, rather than `eval(line)` twice you could store it in a variable, although this is more about preference.

```
perms=["12+2*4","2+2","-2+","12+34-","12-3/4"]
perms.each do |line|
    if (line.to_s =~ /^\d+(?:[+\/*-]\d+)*$/)
        puts "#{line}"
        result = eval(line)
        if(result.to_s =~ /\A\d+\z/)
            puts "#{line}=#{result}"
        end
    end
end
```